# Xamarin Mac Share Extension

Tags: macos, xamarin, share-extension

I am trying to read the path of file that i need to share but it return value as "public.file-url"
Is there any way to read the file path in xamarin mac share extension

Comment: Is this for Mac or iOS? I can not even find a share extension project for Xamarin Mac

Comment: if you are using xamarin just shift to alpha channel  and then try.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using when you are trying to get the file path?

Comment: its solved,thanks..

Comment: i have 1 more thing that i dont know how to do..is how to start main project from share extension project